# how to create 'view migration' script using alembic tool

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, alembic

Does somebody know how to use create_view function to create a view using alembic upgrade function?
for example, we have:

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
 WHERE condition
```

Now we want to define a view in alembic upgrade function script to create 'myview'. How to realize that?

Thanks.

Comment: If alembic doesn't provide the functionality for creating/deleting views, you can always resort to '''op.execute''', which will execute the supplied SQL directly.

Answer (score 13):

I know, the question is way too old and probably the possibility didn't exist at that time. However for all the ones coming to this question now: there exists a possibility now described in the [cookbook](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#replaceable-objects).

It leverages the creation, deletion and replacement of objects like views and stored procedures by giving you additional operations like `op.create_view`, `op.drop_view` or `op.replace_view(myview, replaces="3f2ab897a.myview")`. The same is true for stored procedures and can be also extended for e.g. user defined functions.

A view is defined the following way:

```py
myview = ReplaceableObject('myview',
    """
    SELECT * FROM mytable
    """
)
```

Of course all of this can also be done with simple `op.execute` statements, however in this case alembic takes care of the `DROP VIEW`, `CREATE VIEW` and `ALTER VIEW` commands.

Comment: placing cookbook code in a file 'foo' and  including 'from migrations.foo import *' in env.py was probably obvious to most but wasn't to me. Explicit imports is probably better but ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: @frogg : This probably isn't included in the cookbook (and neither on my answer) as it heavily depends on how you structure your project. E. g. in my case I have the `ReplaceableObject` defined in the package `migrations.helper` and I am importing it in the template `migrations/script.py.mako` in order to have it available in every (generated) revision. On some project I import it directly in the generated revision instead.     
But thank you for clarification, it helps for sure understanding, where the code will land.

Comment: for postgres users: there is a package `alembic_utils` which helps with managing views/functions/materialized views/triggers